# Not receiving webhook photo with location action notifications from Kaizala

Tags: kaizala-action

I have subscribed to a Kaizala webhook with the following request.

```
{  
   "objectId":"XXXXXX",
   "objectType":"Group",
   "eventTypes":[
      "ActionCreated",
      "ActionResponse",
      "SurveyCreated",
      "JobCreated",
      "SurveyResponse",
      "JobResponse",
      "TextMessageCreated",
      "AttachmentCreated",
      "Announcement",
      "MemberAdded",
      "MemberRemoved",
      "GroupAdded",
      "GroupRemoved"
   ],
   "callBackUrl":"XXXXXXX"
}
```

I can receive the photo and location notifications, however, the notification for photo with location does not post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Webhook response is not sent for Photo with location event. But this is a great feedback. We will add this support soon. We will reach out once its implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the information, also, please note that individual location actions are also not being sent as well. The response above will suffice.